# Fantasy/isekai manga where four people, who were abandoned by their respective parties, decide to group up

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

This manga starter off in an inn/bar where two guys and two girls, who are strangers to one another, are sitting at one table and looking all gloomy and depressed because of bad events happening to them recently. They all drunkenly tell their stories to each other and decide to party up. One of the guys has an addiction to idols, while the other one is addicted to brothels, and one of the girls is addicted to gambling, if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 4):

Could this be '*[Apparently, Disillusioned Adventurers Will Save the World](https://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apparently,_Disillusioned_Adventurers_Will_Save_the_World)'* (AKA *Adventurers Who Lost Faith in People Will Apparently Save the World*. AKA *Ningen Fushin no Bōkensha-tachi ga Sekai o Sukuu Yō Desu*)?

> [Nick is] the main protagonist. He was formerly part of the adventurer's party All Martial Arts until he was expelled following an argument caused by his former teammates embezzling funds. Afterward, he is dumped by his supposed girlfriend who was scamming him, and goes through a downward spiral where he wastes his remaining money on idols. However, upon meeting Tiana, Curran, and Zemu and bonding over their shared betrayals, he proposes that they form a new party to fund their spendthrift lifestyles all whilst working to overcome their trust and personality issues, in his case his tendency to talk down to others.
>
> [image]

Comment: And if so, you'll be pleased to learn that this light-novel-turned-manga has an anime adaptation